# Problem in solving conditional probability mentioned below.

Tags: probability-theory

I fail to solve a problem of conditional probability.The problem is "A man seeks advice regarding one of two possible courses of action from three advisers,who arrive at their recommendation independently.He follows the recommendation of the majority.The probabilities that the individual advisers are wrong are 0.1,0.05 and 0.05 respectively.What is the probability that the man takes incorrect advice?"Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

P(follows bad advice ) = 
  P(all three give bad advice) 
+ P(two of the three give bad advice and the other one gives good advice)

$$P=(0.1)(0.05)(0.05) + (0.9)(0.05)(0.05) +  (0.1)(0.95)(0.05) +  (0.1)(0.05)(0.95)  $$